# jquery: how to cycle through multiple items selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, coffeescript

I have a menu bar with top menu items that reflect categories of actions, which are either sort or filtering actions on visible data:

```
<ul class="menu-bar">
        <li class="top-menu-item"><a class="clear-filter">Clear</a></li>
        <li class="top-menu-item"><a><span class="category Category1">Category1</span></a>
          <ul>
           <li><a>FilterAction</a></li>           
            <li><a>SortAction</a></li>           
          </ul>
        <li class="top-menu-item"><a><span class="category Category2">Category2</span></a>
        ...
</ul>
```

When a user selects a sorting or filtering action, I have scripting that currently replaces the text in the appropriate span with the name of the action and adds an appropriate class to the span to designate selection, so that if you selected `FilterAction` in the `Category1` menu, the span would look like this:

```
<span class="category Category1 set-filter">FilterAction</span>
```

and if you selected `SortAction` instead, you would set the span as

```
<span class="category Category1 set-sort">SortAction</span>
```

and if you selected both:

```
<span class="category Category1 set-filter set-sort">SortAction, FilterAction</span>
```

with a sorting action always being listed first.

There can only be one sorting action at any one time, but there is no limit to the number of filters at a time.

To change a sort, since there can only be one at a time, is pretty easy - when I set a new sort, I check to see what existing `set-sort` classes are out there, remove the `set-sort` class and then either replace the text as appropriately with the original category that is retained as a class of the `span` (`Category1` above), or delete all text before the comma, inclusive, so that only the filter text remains. That is working without issue.

Right now the only way to remove filters is to click the `Clear` link, which should replace all of the `span`s that have `set-filter` classes either with the original category names or with existing sort actions.

The trouble I have been having is with being able to select all of the spans with `sort-filter` on them at once and then cycle through to change text and class accordingly. I currently have coffeescript code that does this:

```
$target = $(event.target) # this will be the clear button
$categorySpan = $target.parents(".menu-bar").eq(0).find(".set-filter")
<< code to perform actions on $categorySpan >>
```

right now this obviously doesn't work, it will only perform a blanket action on all selected spans rather than cycle through each span individually. I originally tried it as this instead:

```
for $categorySpan in $target.parents(".menu-bar").eq(0).find(".set-filter")
```

but then I wasn't able to get access to key attributes of the span, like text.

What is the correct way to do this kind of cycling operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of everything that you want to do... but this loop will let you loop through each set-sort span and apply text to the span, or do whatever you want to each one.

```
$('span.set-sort').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.text('Whatever you want').addClass('hello').removeClass('world');
});
```